# How hard should tor aware applications try to share tor daemons?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, development

How advantageous to anonymity is it for different tor aware applications to share a tor daemon instance?

Examples :

- I’m running both TBB and Pond does it improve anonymity much for both TBB and Pond to use the same tor instance?
- I host a hidden service, or even a relay, and occasionally run TBB, should I attempt to coax TBB to use the tor running my hidden service?